# Конвертировать string в int (php)

Tags: php

Имеется данный текст 846,170.7520308043. Подскажите как конвертировать его в число и сократить до двух символов после точки. Спасибо.

Comment: Какое конкретно число вы ожидаете на выходе? `846170.75`?

Comment: `echo round(str_replace(",", "", "846,170.7520308043"),2);` выведет 846170.75